# Custom datetime formats for various locales in Android

Tags: android, localization

I am looking for documentation on how to format dates and times in my Android app for various locales (e.g. Finnish, French, ...etc). I could not find this information in Android's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// (1) get today's date
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

// (2) create our date "formatter" (the date format we want)
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy");

// (3) create a new String using the date format we want
String result = formatter.format(today);

// (4) this prints "Result = Sun Sep 06 08:32:51 2009" in English and will be translated depending on phone Locale
System.out.println("Result = " + result);
```

Source: http://alvinalexander.com/java/simpledateformat-convert-date-to-string-formatted-parse